# VPN between domain and office with no server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, active-directory

IS this even possible? The main office is running server 2008 r2 and is on a domain. The sub office we want to create a vpn connection to does not have a server and just has a regular modem like they would put in your house. IS this setup able to support a vpn connection?

Comment: What's behind the modem in the sub-office?

Comment: a cisco or lynksys wireless router. like the kind you buy at best buy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? You can create Remote Access VPN (use [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725734%28WS.10%29.aspx) article, or any such)
And everybody clients from sub office will be able connect to you LAN.

Comment: To be clear the gateway for the VPN does not need to be in the local office. It can be anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. i just wasn't sure if setting up a windows server to be a remote access server required two servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old "beige box" desktop computer lying around you could install [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) or something similar and use it for your remote office gateway -- it has multiple options for site-to-site VPNs and is very easy to get up and running.

This would keep each user in the remote office from having to configure and run individual VPN clients, and reduce the bandwidth consumed to the overhead of the single tunnel.

Comment: "it has multiple options for site-to-site VPNs and is very easy to get up and running." are you referring to pfSence?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to pfSense -- OpenVPN, IPSec/L2TP, and PPTP (server only, so this one may not be a good site-to-site option) are all supported.  We like OpenVPN a lot and have used that on pfSense for several remote office site-to-site connections for years, but you'd need to install something capable of running OpenVPN on the main office side, too... though another old computer running pfsense would work just fine.  It also has the advantage of being a good gateway/firewall to have on the WAN and can port-forward as necessary for other services.

Comment: i will check into open and and see how it goes. thanks

Comment: ok well i have tried to configure openvpn and for some reason im missing a piece to the puzzle. I have the server installed on a centos box and it has a static private ip. I also i have my public ip. But i cant figure out how to configure it correctly. i have read the admin guide to openvpn and many tutorials but for some reason im missing something. any helpful hits would be greatly appreciated.